# Does a shift register have a voltage drop without any outputs?

Tags: shift-register

I'm still trying to get a full grip with shift registers (and mostly all of electronics), I'm building a circuit that will be run of of an Arduino at 5v, and looking to implement a shift register or two into the design. What I need to know is with 5v, how much power does that shift register use itself, and how much do I have to run two of them. I haven't seen any other questions or advice like this, so I believe it must not be asking the right thing, but what exactly do I need to know to get started?

Thanks!

Comment: look up the specs for the device you chose. It is in there, look for Icc Power Supply CUrrent or some such

Comment: Static power is almost nill. 10~100uA  Dynamic current depends on max clock rate and load capacitance on switched outputs.

Comment: Check out CMOS flip-flops. Unlike TTL, CMOS has no direct paths from VDD to GND. Look up the CMOS version of 74LS194.

Comment: "what exactly do I need to know to get started?" - Read the datasheets of the devices you want to use, and to understand them learn basic electronics from the various online tutorials and/or books available. Use a multimeter to measure actual voltages and currents etc. to verify that the devices are doing what you think they should. There's a lot to learn, which means lots of fun!

Comment: Thanks! Some tutorials and explanations get ahead of my knowledge, and I haven't been to a school which has taught me electronics in full. I'm excited for when circuitlab releases their book!